# Structure field aliasing in C

Tags: c, structure

My design includes two layer which share some of their data with each other.

Lower layer holds some data in a structure:

```
struct Abc {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

I need to export `b` field of the `Abc` structure to upper layer without giving access to rest of fields.
I would like to create a new variable (actually an alias) in upper layer which is located at same memory location as the `b` field. This way both layers share same variable.

Any idea how this can be done without exposing the structure?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
struct Public
{
    int a;
};

struct Private
{
    struct Public p;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

And rely on the C feature that a pointer to a struct can be cast to the type of the first member of that struct, and vice versa.

Probably you can do without the `Public` struct, if it contains just one member, but it is better to be future proof, and you'll never know when you will need more public fields.

Comment: I don't want to access field through pointers. Actually this field is itself a pointer. Making a pointer to this structure would make interface messy. Also the required field cannot be made first.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat: If you want to access to a member of a struct variable from elsewhere, you _must_ use pointers. In C you cannot have two different objects refer to the same memory (other than with unions, and they won't help you here).

Comment: Is there any way using linker directives? Can we using getters and setters force compiler to optimize?

Comment: @HimanshuRawat: Some compilers/linkers may have a way to specify the absolute address of a variable, but that will be totally tool specific (and quite a ugly hack). If you were using C++, you could simply have a global reference, but in C, the normal way is just using a pointer. You can even disguise a pointer with a macro, but that will be even uglier! `int *my_pointer = &abc.b;`, `#define myb (*my_pointer)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by layers here, but I am assuming that you will need access to one of the members of a `struct` which is private to one file.

In that case, you could simply write an `extern` "peek" function to return the value of the particular structure variable you want to expose to other files of your module. This would protect the scope of the rest of the structure while making the value of that one element accessible.

Comment: You can consider lower and upper layer to be middleware and application respectively.

I want application to feel like owning the data. Somewhat like what extern variables.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of access control is doable directly in C++; it is not doable in C.  You'll have to use the discipline of not accessing the members you aren't supposed to access.

There's a partial alternative: you could make the private structure into an opaque pointer, and have a function that knows how to get at the `b` data.  Then the upper layer code need not see anything of the internals of the lower layer data structure.

#### upper.h

```
#include "lower.h"

struct Upper
{
    int p;
    struct Lower *q;
    int r;
};
```

#### lower.h

```
struct Lower *lower_new(void);
void lower_free(struct Lower *);
int lower_b(struct Lower *q);
```

The code needing the `b` field from the lower structure in an instance of the upper structure, `u`, would write:

```
struct Upper u = { ... };
int x = lower_b(u.q);
```

There are many ways to fettle that scheme into one that works for you.  Note that the public header for the lower structure does not define the contents of the structure at all; that is an implementation detail hidden in the source code —`lower.c` presumably.

Comment: I don't want to provide any kind of interface (function) to upper layer.
As variables are in realty just memory locations. "b" field of "Abc" structure would have been allocated some memory location. I want to export this memory location to upper layer.
It is similar to extern(ing) a variable. Only difference here is that variable is not an independent variable but a part (field) of structure.

Comment: OK.  I more or less understand what you want.  I don't think you're going to find that there's a way to achieve what you want in C.